# Minor design updates to site

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some minor updates to site design this week, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Use SVG icons for retina display
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I suppose you've already noticed a couple of bugs/issues reported under [meta-tag:design].

Comment: @DavidZ yep we're fixing them!